# RDLC expression to bind textbox with second rows of datatable

Tags: asp.net, reportviewer

Normally I can bind the first value of DataTable with this expression:

```
First(Fields!ColumnName.Value, "DataSet_Name")
```

How can I get the second value in RDLC ReportViewer like

```
Second(Fields!ColumnName.Value, "DataSet_Name") // This code is error.
```

Thanks :)

Comment: Haven't tried that but mix Lookup/Rownumber might work. Something like `=Lookup(RowNumber("DataSet_Name"), 2, Fields!ColumnName.Value, "DataSet_Name")`

Answer (score -1):

Haven't tried that but mix `Lookup/Rownumber` might work. Something like

```
=Lookup(RowNumber("DataSet_Name"), 2, Fields!ColumnName.Value, "DataSet_Name")
```

---

It not work.

```
Lookup(source_expression, destination_expression, result_expression, dataset)
```

It mean  `value(source_expression) = value(destination_expression)` then get

```
result(result_expression) from same row
```